# Oracle database migration or copy

Tags: oracle

I need to do migrate or copy the oracle 10g database from sun solaris to another sun solaris server (oracle 11g). I was tried with SQL Developer tool. But It is not able copy all the objects in the particular schema. By the same time I should copy objects only, Don't need for data. Is there any procedure or scripts to copy the database or else any Oracle tool ?

Comment: have you tried exp/imp ?

Comment: @Satya  Now I'm doing Database export option in SQL developer. Is it useful ?

Comment: this is, however, as h4b0 has pointed out use Data Pump

Answer (score 4):

The best way to achieve what you want is to do full export/import using [data pump](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g.php) technology.

After successful import, you will probably have to [recompile invalid objects](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/recompiling-invalid-schema-objects.php).

Comment: I would like to add that the author should specify "CONTENT=METADATA_ONLY" in the datapump export, because they specified that they don't need the table data, just the structure.